# How to add multiple lines between code blocks with Prettier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I started using Prettier, but discovered that it doesn't [have an option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) to control the number of blank lines between code blocks, and defaults to one.

I want 2 blank lines:

```
const bar = 10;
// blank 1
// blank 2
function foo() {
  hello();
  world();
}
// blank 1
// blank 2
foo();
// blank 1
// blank 2
export foo;
```

But it defaults to 1 blank line:

```
const bar = 10;
// blank 1
function foo() {
  hello();
  world();
}
// blank 1
foo();
// blank 1
export foo;
```

How can I achieve this with Prettier?

(Or perhaps there is another way to do this. I was surprised how few configurable options are available in Prettier. I was hoping for more control.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to add multiple lines between code blocks with Prettier?

You can't.

> I was surprised how few configurable options are available in Prettier. I was hoping for more control

That is very intentional. `Prettier is an opinionated code formatter.` One of those opinions is 1 line is enough

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Do you know of something similar to Prettier which allows more configuration?

Comment: This is the single rule that will prevent me from ever using prettier. White space is important in code as much as in any design. Otherwise it may as well be machine code.